# Count occurrences of multiple values in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

IF I have a table like this:

```
[1968][?]
[1968][?]
[1968][?]
[1969][?]
[1969][?]
[1970][?]
[1970][?]
```

I want to count the number of times each year occurs in the next column.

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A7,"1968")
```

How can I do this automatically for each year? (because the table is not this small).

Comment: Do it one time? Do it regularly? Have each year once? Repeating the year as the current answer? Without more details this can't be answered well.

Answer (score 1):

I reduced your example data by one row with year 1969 for better result display

```
[1968][=COUNTIF($A$1:$A$6, $A1)]
[1968][=COUNTIF($A$1:$A$6, $A2)]
[1968][=COUNTIF($A$1:$A$6, $A3)]
[1969][=COUNTIF($A$1:$A$6, $A4)]
[1970][=COUNTIF($A$1:$A$6, $A5)]
[1970][=COUNTIF($A$1:$A$6, $A6)]
```

Just enter the formula in B1 and drag-copy it until end of the column B.
Results in

```
[1968][3]
[1968][3]
[1968][3]
[1969][1]
[1970][2]
[1970][2]
```

Comment: if you want to update your answer, here is another possibility: `=COUNTIF(A:A,A:A)`